# jquery multi select, how to get values from function and not on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, handler, multi-select

I am using a jQuery library to manage my mutli selects.

the syntax that works 100% is:

```
$('#multiselectid').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
}).multipleSelect({
    width: '100%'
});
```

when I select items in my multi select I see the logs in the console.

how can I call this from a function though, so the user makes his selections, clicks save. on saving I want to get the value of the multi-select.

so something like:

```
function save(){
     $('#multiselectid').val(function() {
         console.log($(this).val());
     }).multipleSelect({
         width: '100%'
     });
 }
```

This doesnt work and I cant use the normal jquery method to retreive the values as the library modifies the dom to below:

```
<select id="multiselectid" class="multiple" multiple="multiple" type="text" style="display: none;" />
<div class="ms-parent multiple" style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="ms-choice" type="button">
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;">
```

any ideas appreciated as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the documentation.

```
$('#multiselectid').multipleSelect("getSelects"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly use `$('#multiselectid').val()` inorder to get the value.

```
function save() {
    console.log($('#multiselectid').val());
}
```

Comment: Hi,this doesnt work because the input multiselectid doesnt actually contain the value. the html is manipulated but hte multiselect.js to the a div with class `ms-drop `

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this. then we can easily fix this

Comment: @Smudger you are wrong multiselect.js store the value in the select please refer to ressource : http://loudev.com/